# git gitignore and gitmodule

Tags: git, github, gitlab

In GIT, it appears that you cannot add submodules inside the directory structure of other submodules. A submodule path inside a project is automatically in gitignore. Is there a way around this?

For instance suppose you are configuring a project with the following directory structure:

```
Project
 -----|___SubModule1  
 ------------------|___SubModule2
```

but you dont wish to associate SubModule2 with the repository of SubModule1 (i.e. you can do this in two steps by adding SubModule2 as a submodule to SubModule1 and then SubModule1 as a submodule to Project).

Rather you wish to manage this association in your Project which simply holds the configuration (i.e. if SubModule2 is a plugin for the SubModule1 middleware). How can this be handled...?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but if `SubModule2` is a Submodule in `SubModule1`, you cannot "manage" it from `Project` (as long as "manage" means more than trigger a recursive submodule update or init or the like).

Comment: Suppose SubModule1 is a framework with "Plugins" directory and you wish to add a few plugins at particular versions that are applicable only to Project but are not applicable in general when updating/cloning SubModule1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your submodule to contain content (i.e. Plugins) specific to your parent repository `project`. Please correct me if I missed something. I will describe the necessary steps in command line.

This can easily be solved by creating a branch in your submodule repository. From your parent repository, change into your Submodule:

```
cd SubModule1
git checkout -b project/plugins
```

Now add the necessary plugins to the created branch, commit and push this commit containing the desired plugins.

```
//copy plugins or whatever
git add plugins/requiredPlugin
git commit -m "Add project-specific plugins"
git push
```

You will then have the new branch created on your remote with the new commit as it's `HEAD`, containing the plugins you desired, while the rest of the `SubModule1` repository is untouched.

Back in the parent repository, you will see that the submodule changed. That is, of course, because it now points to a different commit than before: the commit containing the plugins. You can now add and commit the changes and will have your parent repository point to a commit in a branch of the submodule that contains your specific plugins.

```
cd ..
git status
//see that SubModule1/ has changed
git add SubModule1
git commit -m "Update submodule to plugin branch"
```